# theano:simple neural network with 6 layers trains with only 132 datapoints per second. Why is it so slow?

Tags: openmp, gpu, nvidia, theano, hardware-acceleration

I have a quite small neural network with two fully connected sigmoid subnetworks 10->100->10, whose output is concatenated and then fed into another 20->100->1 network.
This architecture is quite small, having just a few weights matrices that have maximum dimension 20x100=2000 weights.

Even if I am using theano with all flags set to use gpu acceleration, the system reaches only 132 iterations (datapoints!) per second. I am not using minibatches because it's not your typical neural network, but a matrix factorization model.

The system I am using has the following specs:

**OS**

```
uname -a
Linux node081 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 28 17:19:38 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**software**

- Python 3.5.2 (compiled by myself)
- theano 0.9.0dev2.dev-ee4c4e21b9e9037f2aa9626c3d779382840ea2e3
- NumPy 1.11.2

**cpu**

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz
```

with `nproc` that returns `12`, hence might have 12 processors (or cores?)

**gpu**

this is the output of `nvidia-smi` (with my process running):

```
+------------------------------------------------------+                
| NVIDIA-SMI 5.319.49   Driver Version: 319.49         |                   
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K20m          On   | 0000:03:00.0     Off |                  Off |
| N/A   29C    P0    49W / 225W |       92MB /  5119MB |     19%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      5903  python3                                               77MB  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**command and env vars**

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,init_gpu_device=gpu,floatX=float32,nvcc.flags=-D_FORCE_INLINES,print_active_device=True,enable_initial_driver_test=True,warn_float64=raise,force_device=True,assert_no_cpu_op=raise python3 $@
```

**theano config settings set at run-time**

```
theano.config.optimizer='fast_run'
theano.config.openmp=True
theano.config.openmp_elemwise_minsize=4
theano.config.floatX='float32'
theano.config.assert_no_cpu_op='raise'
```

I also tried to deactivate openmp, and it works slightly slower.

It seems that I took all the precautions to make sure I have gpu acceleration correctly set. What might the reason of getting only 132 gradient updates at every second? Is there any further check I need to perform?

Answer (score 1):

In theano,

- The compilation is much faster on `optimizer=fast_compile` than with `optimizer=fast_run`.
- Using the new-backend, with the help of new optimizer, compilation time has increased by 5X on certain networks. I'd suggest you should always stick with the new backend. You can use the new backend by using `device=cuda`flag.
- While you're using the new backend, I'd advice you to use the bleeding edge if you want speed. There are a lot of optimizations being done every week that has potential to give great speeds.
- From the docs, you can set the flag `allow_gc=False`to get faster speed
- You can set config.nvcc.fastmath flag to True if you require some speed up from the division and multiplication operations at the cost of precision.
- If you have convolutional operations in your network, you can set some `config.dnn` flags depending upon your network and needs. Also, setting cnmem flag will help.
- Finally, whenever you're reporting a code to be slow, please share profiling results for helping the development :)

Comment: what I did was restructuring the code in order to make minibatches possible. With a minibatch size of 64 I got about 40x speedup. I might try your suggestions sooner or later.

Comment: Since on a GPU, matrix - matrix multiplications are much faster than matrix - vector, I suggest you set an optimal mini-batch size that will allow you to use the almost the full GPU memory so that you could compute the gradient faster and in more efficient way

Comment: True, there is a catch tough: the minibatch size affects the learning too: the larger the minibatch, the less the "stochastic" beneficial effects from the Stochastic Gradient Descent.